# Tangent to hyperbola meeting on ellipse

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, tangent-line, billiards

Can anyone prove that the two tangent lines to hyperbola that meet on a confocal ellipse make the same angle with the tangent of the ellipse at the point of intersection?

Thanks

Comment: Why is this in a billiards tag?

Comment: @BrianTung Because it is about billiards. It is about the fact that a billiard trajectory on an elliptical billiard table is always tangent to a confocal conic section (a hyperbola or an ellipse, depending on whether the foci are externally located with respect to the trajectory or the trajectory encompasses the foci)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Alternative formulation.** *Let us have an ellipse and a hyperbola that share the same pair of foci $F_1$ and $F_2$. Let point $E$ be a point on the ellipse and let the lines $t_1$ and $t_2$ be the two tangents to the hyperbola that pass through the point $E$. Let $H_1$ and $H_2$ be the points where the lines $t_1$ and $t_2$ touch the hyperbola respectively. 
Let $t_E$ be the line tangent to the ellipse at point $E$ with $E1$ and $E2$ two arbitrary points chosen on $t_E$ so that $E$ is between $E_1$ and $E_2$, as shown on the figure. Prove that 
$$\angle \, E_1EH_1 = \angle \, E_2EH_2$$*

$$ $$

[image]

*Proof.* Let $F_1$ and $F_2$ be the foci of the hyperbola in question. Let $H_1$ and $H_2$ be two points from the hyperbola and let lines $t_1$ and $t_2$ be the two tangents to the hyperbola at the points $H_1$ and $H_2$ respectively. Take the unique ellipse with foci $F_1$ and $F_2$ that passes through point $E = t_1 \cap t_2$. Indeed, this is the ellipse, formed by all points $X$ in the planes such that $$F_1X + XF_2 = F_1E + EF_2$$ The line $t_E$ is the tangent line to the ellipse at the point $E$ and points $E_1$ and $E_2$ are two arbitrary points chosen on $t_E$ so that $E$ is between $E_1$ and $E_2$, as shown on the figure.

[image]

By the reflective properties of ellipses, 
$$\angle \, E_1EF_1 = \angle \, E_2EF_2 = \alpha$$
By the reflective properties of hyperbolas, 
$$\angle \, F_1H_1E = \angle \, F_2H_1E \,\, \text{ and } \,\, 
\angle \, F_1H_2E = \angle \, F_2H_2E$$ 
Let the line through point $F_1$ orthogonal to $t_1 = H_1E$ intersects $H_1F_2$ at point $S_1$, and let he line through point $F_2$ orthogonal to $t_2 = H_2E$ intersects $H_2F_1$ at point $S_2$. Since $t_1$ is the angle bisector of $\angle \, F_1H_1F_2$ and $t_2$ is the angle bisector of $\angle\, F_1H_2F_2$, the two triangles $F_1H_1S_1$ and $F_2H_2S_2$ are isosceles with $H_1F_1 = H_1S_1$ and $H_2F_2 = H_2S_2$ respectively.

By the properties of the hyperbola, $$F_1S_2 = F_1H_2 - H_2S_2 = F_1H_2 - H_2F_2 = F_2H_1 - H_1F_1 = F_2H_1 - H_1S_1 = F_2S_1$$
Furthermore, by construction, line $t_1 = H_1E$ is the orthogonal bisector of segment $F_1S_1$, and  line $t2 = H_2E$ is the orthogonal bisector of segment $F_2S_2$. Therefore, $EF_1 = ES_1$ and $EF_2 = ES_2$. Combined with the fact that $F_1S_2 = F_2S_1$, all of these identities yield that triangles $EF_1S_2$ and $EF_2S_1$ are congruent. Hence, $$\angle \, F_1ES_2 = \angle \, S_1EF_2 = \beta$$ Let $\angle \, S_2ES_1 = \theta$. Then $$\angle \, F_1ES_1 = \angle \, F_1ES_2 + \angle \, S_2ES_1 = \beta + \theta = \theta + \beta = \angle \, S_2ES_1 + \angle \, S_1EF_2 = \angle \, S_2EF_2$$ and for that reason $$\angle \, F_1EH_1 = \frac{1}{2} \, \angle \, F_1ES_1 = \frac{1}{2} \, (\beta + \theta) =  \frac{1}{2} \, \angle \, S_2ES_2 = \angle \, F_2EH_2$$

Finally, 
$$\angle \, E_1EH_1 = \angle \, E_1EF_1 + \angle \, F_1EH_1 =\alpha + \frac{1}{2}(\beta + \theta)$$ and
$$\angle \, E_2EH_2 = \angle \, E_2EF_2 + \angle \, F_2EH_2 =\alpha + \frac{1}{2}(\beta + \theta)$$ Hence
$$\angle \, E_1EH_1 = \angle \, E_2EH_2$$

Comment: Please draw one image of hyperbola and ellipse. I don't understand the question at all, though.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki There.

Comment: Nice. I knew two line are tanget to hyperbola with same angle from tangents of ellipse.